# Any video baby monitors with multiple receivers?

Tags: infant, newborn, gadgets

I am looking for a video monitor for an infant. If possible, I want to have multiple receivers for one camera, so it isn't necessary to carry the receiver around everywhere.

Summer Infant offers the [Baby Touch Wifi](http://www.summerinfant.com/babytouchwifi); it comes with a receiver, but the camera can also be viewed on an iOS device using the [SummerLink app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/summer-link/id732316361?mt=8). This solution is not acceptable to me because I find the app unusably bad.

Summer Infant also makes the [Dual Coverage](http://www.summerinfant.com/dualcoverage), which is the only dual-receiver video monitor I have seen. Given my unsatisfying prior experience with another of Summer's products (and many hours of experience with their customer service), I am hesitant to try this monitor.

Are there any other video baby monitors that can be used with multiple receivers?

Comment: Unless you are cool with the idea of persons unknown snooping on your sleeping baby, make sure that you take time to check the security and enable any settings. Security is not a selling point for these devices, so it gets neglected by the manufacturers, and to avoid customer complaints they configure the devices to work out of the box with just the default passwords.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into putting in an IP camera instead?  We have two of the [Foscam FI8910W cameras](http://foscam.us/foscam-fi8910w-wireless-ip-camera.html?gclid=CPDEvrbd-LwCFeRi7AodpV4AHQ), one in each child's room.  We hooked them up to the wireless and then use any number of free or cheap apps to see the cameras on our phones, as well as just using the IP address assigned to the camera to view them on our laptops.

We had one bad camera, which was constantly losing its IP address, but Foscam's customer service was great and replaced it without a lot of fanfare.

Comment: Using a webcam is a possibility I have explored, but I would prefer to have at least one dedicated receiver rather than using an app or a browser to view the video. I want to be able to carry the viewing device around with me, which a phone can certainly do, but I want to be able to use my phone for other things which watching the video and not drain my phone's battery by leaving it on and streaming for a long time. A webcam may end up being the best option that fits the most of my constraints, but I want to make sure I find every possibility before I decide.

Comment: The battery life is definitely a consideration.  We deal with it by having chargers available all around the house so when we are stopped in one place for a while, we can plug it in and not have it chew the battery to shreds.

Comment: We felt the same way about a dedicated viewer and feel it has many advantages. But we were never happy with the one viewer limit on our Summer device either. In retrospect I might have gone with an IP camera solution and bought an old ipod touch. Anything that used a web interface would work fine even on the oldest of them & I'd be able to set a screen timeout which the Summer does not allow me to configure.